# Geb tests fail with geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException in PhantomJS, Pass is Chrome & Firefox

Tags: selenium, grails, phantomjs, geb

I am in the process of implementing Geb/Selenium in a Grails/Angular application. I am new to both Geb & Selenium. When running the following Geb test:

```
def "navigate to User edit page" () {
    given:
        login(admin, pass)
    when:
        waitFor { to UserListPage }
    then:
        at (new UserListPage())
        waitFor { userList.hasUser("admin") }
        userList.hasUser("marisa.adelman")
    when:
        userList.clickUser("marisa.adelman")
    then:
        waitFor(60) { at (new UserMaintenancePage()) }
}
```

The line `userList.clickUser("marisa.adelman")` finds the row in a table for the user provided and clicks it to load the maintenance page. The test passes in both Chrome and Firefox, but fails when I run it in PhantomJS with a WaitTimeoutException as follows:

```
    Failure:  |
navigate to User edit page(vdo.auth.AdminFunctionalSpec)
 |
geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 60.0 seconds.     Failed with exception:
geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 10.0 seconds.     Failed with exception:
Assertion failed: 

$("form", id: "frmUserCreateEdit")
|
[]

at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:138)
at geb.waiting.DefaultWaitingSupport.doWaitFor(DefaultWaitingSupport.groovy:51)
at geb.waiting.DefaultWaitingSupport.waitFor(DefaultWaitingSupport.groovy:42)
at geb.Page.waitFor(Page.groovy:511)
at geb.Browser.methodMissing(Browser.groovy:207)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:56)
at vdo.auth.AdminFunctionalSpec.navigate to User edit         page(AdminFunctionalSpec.groovy:123)
Caused by: geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 10.0         seconds. Failed with exception:
Assertion failed: 

$("form", id: "frmUserCreateEdit")
|
[]

at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:138)
at geb.Page.verifyThisPageAtOnly(Page.groovy:226)
at geb.Page.verifyAt(Page.groovy:182)
at geb.Browser.doAt(Browser.groovy:455)
at geb.Browser.at(Browser.groovy:354)
at geb.spock.GebSpec.methodMissing(GebSpec.groovy:56)
at vdo.auth.AdminFunctionalSpec.navigate to User edit     page_closure13(AdminFunctionalSpec.groovy:123)
at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:127)
... 6 more
```

Caused by: Assertion failed:

```
$("form", id: "frmUserCreateEdit")
|
[]

at     vdo.auth.pages.UserMaintenancePage._clinit__closure1(UserMaintenancePage.groovy:1    0)
at geb.waiting.Wait.waitFor(Wait.groovy:127)
... 13 more
```

I've tried setting the timeout on the individual waitFor anywhere from 10 to 60 seconds; the GebConfig timeout anywhere from 10 to 60 seconds. `atCheckWaiting` is set to true on the UserMaintenancePage, etc. All with no luck.

Am I missing a PhantomJS configuration setting, or is there some sort of workaround for this that will actually test the link to the page? Any other pointers would be appreciated

Comment: What's the output of the tests? Maybe on phantomJs folder results you found an empty html and empty screenshot? If yes, I was having same weirds behaviours (tests worked fine in chrome or firefox but fails under phantomJs) and was caused by my corporate Kaspersky antivirus. Once disabled it started working again...